# Given $G = \{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1, x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0\}$ find angles

Tags: calculus

Given $G = \{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1, x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0\}$ find angles and find radius

Well, In the solution it says that it is eigth of a ball, and angles are from $0$ to $90$ degrees, both angles (teta and $\phi$). and radius is from $0$ to $1$ which is true because $r = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1$.

But, I don't understand how they calculated 90 degrees. If it was 4th a ball, then I could understand that it is 90. but for me it seems like $180/8 = 22.5 $degrees.

What am I missing here?

Edit: Maybe it is because $sin$, $cos$ are positive ($\ge 0$) from $0$ to $90$ degrees, that why this is the range?

Comment: There are two angle coordinates, one with value from 0° to 360° (longitude), the other from -90° to +90° (latitude). So if you take a fourth of the range of the first coordinates (between 0 and 90°) and half of the range of the second (also between 0 and 90°), you get one eighth of the ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $x=\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi$ , $x=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z=\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi$. In spherical coordinate we have
$$\rho\ge 0$$ 
$$0\le \theta\le 2\pi$$ 
$$0\le \phi \le \pi$$ 
[image]

If $x,y\ge 0$ then $0\le \theta\le \frac \pi 2$

If $z\ge 0$ then $0\le \phi\le \frac \pi 2$

Comment: How can $\phi$ reach to $\pi$ isnt it supposed to be from -90 to 90? and because of $z \ge 0$ it will be from $0$ to $90$ ?

Comment: please look at the figure, since $z\ge 0$ , we have $\phi \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}, ]$

Comment: Exactly.Thx sir

Answer (score 1):

Basically the comment in your edit is correct:

Given the usual spherical coordinates

\begin{align*}x& =r \, \sin\theta \, \cos\varphi\\
y& =r \, \sin\theta \, \sin\varphi \qquad r\in[0,R],\theta\in[0,\pi),\varphi\in[0,2\pi)\\ z&=r \, \cos\theta,
\end{align*}

you immediately see that in order to get a positive $z$ coordinate you need $\theta$ to lie in $[0,\pi/2],$ but then $\sin(\theta)$ is also positive there, and so you need to have $\varphi$ also in the first quadrant $\left([0,\pi/2]\right)$ to have **both** $\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi$ simultaneously positive.

Answer (score 1):

A geometric argument like the one Behrouz Maleki gives is the easiest way to solve this,but I think it's worth the effort to seeing how a calculational argument would look.

The simplest way to do this is to convert the rectangular coordinates of the sphere to spherical coordinates.

(1) $x^2 + y^2+ z^2 \leq 1$

(2)$\rho^2\leq 1$

(3) x =$\rho\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\geq 0$

(4) y=$\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\geq 0$

(5) z=$\rho\cos(\phi)\geq 0$

We need $0\leq \rho \leq 1$ and we're given that $x,y,z \geq 0$.Using these bounds in equation (5) yields  $0\leq\cos(\phi)\leq 1$ or $0\leq\phi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.Now square (3) and (4),add them and let z=0.This gives:

(6)  $x^2 + y^2 =\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\phi)+ \rho^2\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)$ $\rightarrow $

$\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)(\cos^2(\phi)+ sin^2(\phi))= \rho^2\sin^2(\theta)$

Substituting the value ranges of $\rho$ and $\psi$ give: 
  $0\leq \sin^2(\theta)\leq 1$ $\rightarrow $ $|sin(\theta)|\leq 1$

And this implies $0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.